# HTMLUnit Wait For JS Issue

Tags: java, javascript, htmlunit

I'm using HTMLUnit in order to put text in a input box and then clicking on a link which is actually a JS call.
The problem comes up when I put text in an input , using `inputBox.setValueAttribute("example input");` . In this case , after clicking the button the page does not change at all.
On the other hand , once I delete `inputBox.setValueAttribute("example input");` and then click the button, the page content does change and includes an error for empty input.

Below is the code i've used in order to put text in the relevant input and then click the button.

```
public void addressToBlockPlot(){
        WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);
        client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        client.setJavaScriptTimeout(10000);
        client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        client.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        client.getOptions().setTimeout(10000);


        try {
            HtmlPage page = client.getPage("http://mapi.gov.il/Pages/LotAddressLocator.aspx");

            HtmlInput inputBox = (HtmlInput)page.getHtmlElementById("AddressInput");
            final HtmlAnchor a = (HtmlAnchor) page.getElementById("helkaSubmit");

            inputBox.setValueAttribute("example input");

            a.click();
            client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(2000); 
            HtmlPage page2= (HtmlPage) client.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage(); 

            System.out.println(page2.asXml());

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
```

Any ideas for solving this issue ?

**EDIT:**
I've tried using  `inputBox.setValueAttribute("");` , which resulted in receiving the same error that I got when no input text was set at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have almost similar issue, where JS take some time to load, I have solved this issue by setting wait and retries until page load successfully by adding a condition,

```
    int input_length = page.getByXPath("//input").size();
    int tries = 5;
    while (tries > 0 && input_length < 12) {
        tries--;
        synchronized (page) {
            page.wait(2000);
        }
        input_length = page.getByXPath("//input").size();
        System.out.println("page loaded successfully");
    }
```

here input_length determines that whether required page is loaded or not. you can use similar condition according to structure of your page.